# How to parse a syslog message with pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have syslog that like below.

date=2015-10-08 time=16:03:26 devname=D1_FIG device_id=ID300B3908601UID log_id=0021000002 type=traffic subtype=allowed pri=notice vd=root src=157.56.15.15 src_port=3584 src_int="port4" dst=211.16.12.55 dst_port=80 dst_int="WLN_200" SN=2775431942 status=accept policyid=430 dst_country="United Kingdom, Great Britain" src_country="United Kingdom, Great Britain" dir_disp=org tran_disp=dnat tran_ip=12.15.7.17 tran_port=80 service=HTTP proto=6 duration=120 sent=132 rcvd=92 sent_pkt=3 rcvd_pkt=2

I want to parse this log using pyparsing like this.

```
{"date", "2015-10-08"}
{"time", "16:03:26"}
{"devname", "D1_FIG"}
{"device_id", "ID300B3908601UID"}
....
{"src", "157.56.15.15"}
....
{"dst_country", "United Kingdom, Great Britain"}
....
```

source code is like this.

```
from pyparsing import *

origin_str = "date=2015-10-08 time=16:03:26 devname=D1_FIG device_id=ID300B3908601UID log_id=0021000002 type=traffic subtype=allowed pri=notice vd=root src=157.56.15.15 src_port=3584 src_int=\"port4\" dst=211.16.12.55 dst_port=80 dst_int=\"WLN_200\" SN=2775431942 status=accept policyid=430 dst_country=\"United Kingdom, Great Britain\" src_country=\"United Kingdom, Great Britain\" dir_disp=org tran_disp=dnat tran_ip=12.15.7.17 tran_port=80 service=HTTP proto=6 duration=120 sent=132 rcvd=92 sent_pkt=3 rcvd_pkt=2"

date_s = Word(nums, nums+'-')
time_s = Word(nums, nums+':')
identifier = Word(alphas, alphanums+'_') | date_s | time_s
equal = Literal("=").suppress()
KeyNValue = identifier.setResultsName("lhs") + equal + identifier.setResultsName("rhs")

for srvrtokens,startloc,endloc in KeyNValue.scanString(origin_str):
    print srvrtokens
```

This is what I have so far:

```
['date', '2015-10-08']
['time', '16']
['devname', 'FW_IDC1']
['device_id', 'FG300B3908601477']
['log_id', '0021000002']
['type', 'traffic']
['subtype', 'allowed']
['pri', 'notice']
['vd', 'root']
['src', '147']
['src_port', '58979']
['dst', '210']
['dst_port', '80']
['SN', '2770251942']
['status', 'accept']
['policyid', '430']
['dir_disp', 'org']
['tran_disp', 'dnat']
['tran_ip', '172']
['tran_port', '80']
['service', 'HTTP']
['proto', '6']
['duration', '120']
['sent', '132']
['rcvd', '92']
['sent_pkt', '3']
['rcvd_pkt', '2']
```

But I don't know how to parse "time" and "dst_country" string.

Comment: Your desired output isn't quite a `dict` or `list`.  What exactly is the form of your desired result?

Comment: It does not matter either. My problem is parsing. And your answer is solve my problem!

Answer (score 1):

This program produces a `dict` of the data in the log string.

```
from pyparsing import *
from pprint import pprint

origin_str = "date=2015-10-08 time=16:03:26 devname=D1_FIG device_id=ID300B3908601UID log_id=0021000002 type=traffic subtype=allowed pri=notice vd=root src=157.56.15.15 src_port=3584 src_int=\"port4\" dst=211.16.12.55 dst_port=80 dst_int=\"WLN_200\" SN=2775431942 status=accept policyid=430 dst_country=\"United Kingdom, Great Britain\" src_country=\"United Kingdom, Great Britain\" dir_disp=org tran_disp=dnat tran_ip=12.15.7.17 tran_port=80 service=HTTP proto=6 duration=120 sent=132 rcvd=92 sent_pkt=3 rcvd_pkt=2"

key = Word(alphas, alphanums+'_')
value = quotedString | Word(printables)
equal = Literal("=").suppress()
KeyNValue = key + equal + value

result = dict(srvtokens for srvtokens,_,_ in KeyNValue.scanString(origin_str))
assert len(result) == origin_str.count('=')

pprint(result)
```

result:

```
{'SN': '2775431942',
 'date': '2015-10-08',
 'device_id': 'ID300B3908601UID',
 'devname': 'D1_FIG',
 'dir_disp': 'org',
 'dst': '211.16.12.55',
 'dst_country': '"United Kingdom, Great Britain"',
 'dst_int': '"WLN_200"',
 'dst_port': '80',
 'duration': '120',
 'log_id': '0021000002',
 'policyid': '430',
 'pri': 'notice',
 'proto': '6',
 'rcvd': '92',
 'rcvd_pkt': '2',
 'sent': '132',
 'sent_pkt': '3',
 'service': 'HTTP',
 'src': '157.56.15.15',
 'src_country': '"United Kingdom, Great Britain"',
 'src_int': '"port4"',
 'src_port': '3584',
 'status': 'accept',
 'subtype': 'allowed',
 'time': '16:03:26',
 'tran_disp': 'dnat',
 'tran_ip': '12.15.7.17',
 'tran_port': '80',
 'type': 'traffic',
 'vd': 'root'}
```

Comment: Sometimes the disconnect between the parsed structure and the desired one forces this kind of post-parse structure building.  But in this case, you can have pyparsing build the dict for you at parse time using the Dict class: `result = Dict(OneOrMore(Group(KeyNValue))).parseString(origin_str).asDict()` .  The OP can also make the value more discriminating with type-specific formats and parse-time converters added as parse actions to give actual ints, floats, datetimes, etc. instead of just strings. But those are all good follow-up exercises for the reader. Nice answer!

Comment: Perfect answer. Robᵩ. Would you explain " srvtokens for srvtokens,_,_ in KeyNValue.scanString(origin_str)" to me? and Paul's answer is nice too!.